# hover column graphael

Tags: javascript, graphael

Estou a utilisar a livraria graphael para desenhar um grafico de linhas. Queri que ao passa-se com o rato, mostrar os dois valores, x e y. Neste caso so consigo mostrar o valor de y. 
Como posso mostrar os dois?
Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/aNJxf/18/

```
.hoverColumn(function () {
    this.tags = r.set();

    for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
        this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));

    }, function () {
        this.tags && this.tags.remove();
        });
```

Comment: No meu o fiddle aparece correcto. Aparece o gráfico, so não consigo mostrar os valores de x e y quando movo por cima dos circulos das linhas.

Comment: Como posso agora ver os dois valores x e y na label do hover? Porque utilizo this.values no text e aparece so o valor y.